# Implementing Content-Based Router Pattern in Akka

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel, akka, actor

I am trying to implement a [content-based router](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/ContentBasedRouter.html) in my Akka actor system and according to [this document](https://gist.github.com/jboner/8556813) the [ConsistentHashingRouter](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/java/routing.html) is the way to go. After reading through its official docs, I still find myself confused as to how to use this built-in hashing router. I think that’s because the router itself is hash/key-based, and the example the Akka doc author chose to use was a scenario involving key-value based caches…so I can’t tell which keys are used by the cache and which ones are used by the router!

Let’s take a simple example. Say we have the following messages:

```
interface Notification {
    // Doesn’t matter what’s here.
}

// Will eventually be emailed to someone.
class EmailNotification implements Notification {
    // Doesn’t matter what’s here.
}

// Will eventually be sent to some XMPP client and on to a chatroom somewhere.
class ChatOpsNotifications implements Notification {
    // Doesn’t matter what’s here.
}
```

etc. In theory we might have 20 `Notification` impls. I’d like to be able to send a `Notification` to an actor/router at runtime and have that router route it to the correct `NotificationPubisher`:

```
interface NotificationPublisher<NOTIFICATION implements Notification> {
    void send(NOTIFICATION notification)
}

class EmailNotificationPublisher extends UntypedActor implements NotificationPubisher<EmailNotification> {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof EmailNotification) {
            send(message as EmailNotification)
        }
    }

    @Override
    void send(EmailNotification notification) {
        // Use Java Mail, etc.
    }
}

class ChatOpsNotificationPublisher extends UntypedActor implements NotificationPubisher<ChatOpsNotification> {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof ChatOpsNotification) {
            send(message as ChatOpsNotification)
        }
    }

    @Override
    void send(ChatOpsNotification notification) {
        // Use XMPP/Jabber client, etc.
    }
}
```

Now I *could* do this routing myself, manually:

```
class ReinventingTheWheelRouter extends UntypedActor {
    // Inject these via constructor
    ActorRef emailNotificationPublisher
    ActorRef chatOpsNotificationPublisher
    // ...20 more publishers, etc.

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        ActorRef publisher
        if(message instanceof EmailNotification) {
            publisher = emailNotificationPublisher
        } else if(message instanceof ChatOpsNotification) {
            publisher = chatOpsNotificationPublisher
        } else if(...) { ... } // 20 more publishers, etc.

        publisher.tell(message, self)
    }
}
```

Or I *could* use the [Akka-Camel module](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/camel.html) to defined a Camel-based router and send `Notifications` off to the Camel router, but it seems that Akka aready has this built-in solution, so why not use it? I just cant figure out how to translate the `Cache` example from those Akka docs to my `Notification` example here. What’s the purpose of the “key” in the `ConsistentHashingRouter`? What would the code look like to make this work?

**Of course I would appreciate any answer that helps me solve this, but would greatly prefer Java-based code snippets if at all possible. Scala looks like hieroglyphics to me.**

---

I agree that a [Custom Router](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/java/routing.html#Custom_Router) is more appropriate than `ConsistentHashingRouter`. After reading the docs on custom routers, it seems I would:

1. Create a `GroupBase` impl and send messages to it directly (`notificationGroup.tell(notification, self)`); then
2. The `GroupBase` impl, say, `NotificationGroup` would provide a `Router` instance that was injected with my custom `RoutingLogic` impl
3. When `NotificationGroup` receives a message, it executes my custom `RoutingLogic#select` method which determines which `Routee` (I presume some kind of an actor?) to send the message to

If this is correct (and **please correct me if I’m wrong**), then the routing selection magic happens here:

```
class MessageBasedRoutingLogic implements RoutingLogic {
    @Override
    Routee select(Object message, IndexedSeq<Routee> candidates) {
        // How can I query the Routee interface and deterine whether the message at-hand is in fact
        // appropriate to be routed to the candidate?
        //
        // For instance I'd like to say "If message is an instance of
        // an EmailNotification, send it to EmailNotificationPublisher."
        //
        // How do I do this here?!?
        if(message instanceof EmailNotification) {
            // Need to find the candidate/Routee that is
            // the EmailNotificationPublisher, but how?!?
        }
    }
}
```

But as you can see I have a few mental implementation hurdles to cross. The `Routee` interface doesn’t really give me anything I can intelligently use to decide whether a particular `Routee` (candidate) is correct for the message at hand.

So I ask: (1) How can I map messages to `Routees` (effectively performing the route selection/logic)? (2) How do I add my publishers as routees in the first place? And (3) Do my `NotificationPublisher` impls still need to extend `UntypedActor` or should they now implement `Routee`?

Comment: I don't think you need a consistent hash router for your needs.  That router ensures that a unique instance of a message (unique by a defined property) is always handled by the same instance of a given actor.  That's very fine grained routing.  Your's seems a bit more coarse.  You just need to route by type to a particular actor instance.  I would just build a custom router for this as defined here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/java/routing.html#Custom_Router

Comment: Thanks for the sound advice @cmbaxter (+1) - please see my updates regarding custom routers as this idea has spun up a few followup questions! Thanks again!

Comment: I can give you a rough sketch in Scala.  I don't have the time to port it over to Java

Comment: Also remember that the only advantage of a custom router over just a regular actor doing the routing is speed.  If speed and super high performance are not of concern just go with a regular actor.  It's much simpler. Akka suggests as much in their documentation for the custom router.

Comment: Thanks again @cmbaxter (+1 for both) - yes please if you can whip me up *anything* (even in Scala) and put it in answer-form I will happily accept it! And yes speed will be very important here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple little A/B router in Scala.  I hope this helps even though you wanted a Java based answer.  First the routing logic:

```
class ABRoutingLogic(a:ActorRef, b:ActorRef) extends RoutingLogic{
  val aRoutee = ActorRefRoutee(a)
  val bRoutee = ActorRefRoutee(b)

  def select(msg:Any, routees:immutable.IndexedSeq[Routee]):Routee = {
    msg match{
      case "A" => aRoutee
      case _ => bRoutee
    }
  }
}
```

The key here is that I am passing in my `a` and `b` actor refs in the constructor and then those are the ones I am routing to in the `select` method.  Then, a `Group` for this logic:

```
case class ABRoutingGroup(a:ActorRef, b:ActorRef) extends Group { 
  val paths = List(a.path.toString, b.path.toString)

  override def createRouter(system: ActorSystem): Router =
    new Router(new ABRoutingLogic(a, b))

  val routerDispatcher: String = Dispatchers.DefaultDispatcherId
}
```

Same thing here, I am making the actors I want to route to available via the constructor.  Now a simple actor class to act as `a` and `b`:

```
class PrintingActor(letter:String) extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case msg => println(s"I am $letter and I received letter $msg") 
  }
}
```

I will create two instances of this, each with a different letter assignment so we can verify that the right ones are getting the right messages per the routing logic.  Lastly, some test code:

```
object RoutingTest extends App{
  val system = ActorSystem()
  val a = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[PrintingActor], "A"))
  val b = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[PrintingActor], "B"))
  val router = system.actorOf(Props.empty.withRouter(ABRoutingGroup(a,b)))

  router ! "A"
  router ! "B"

}
```

If you ran this, you would see:

```
I am A and I received letter A
I am B and I received letter B
```

It's a very simple example, but one that shows one way to do what you want to do.  I hope you can bridge this code into Java and use it to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much @cmbaxter (+1) - one last tiny question if you don't mind: it would be nice if I could combine this custom router with `Patterns.ask(...)` so as to achieve non-blocking behavior with the routees. In other words: I issue a `Patterns.ask(abRoutingGroup, someMsg)`, and the group routes `someMsg` to either `aRoutee` or `bRoutee` respectively, but in an asynchronous/non-blocking fashion. Is this possible to do, or do custom routers like the one above force synchronous/blocking interactions? Thanks again!!!

Comment: This is completely async and when the router passes the message to the actual routee, the original sender is preserved (it's a forward vs a tell to the routee from the router), so you can certainly use ask.